# How to access value inside String. Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http

This is my code :

```
    String text = snapshot.data[index];
     var splitText = text.split("\n") ;

final jdata = jsonEncode(splitText[5]);

                          print(jdata);
```

which prints the String :

```
"RunHyperlink : {classid: 25510, id: 2, mad_key: 32835}"
```

snapshot.data[index] contains :

```
I/flutter (14351): Code : LE-0000000002
I/flutter (14351): Description : test_01
I/flutter (14351): Organisation Unit : 01_01_04_01_SA - Shah Alam
I/flutter (14351): Date Reported : 18/09/2020
I/flutter (14351): Status : LE110 - Pending Approval
I/flutter (14351): RunHyperlink : {classid: 25510, id: 2, mad_key: 32835}
```

my question is how do I access the value of "id".

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please attach the result of `text`?

Comment: @AnkitTale even if dont encode it, how would I access "id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          String temp;
          const start = " id:";
          const end = ",";
          if (str.contains(start)) {
            final startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
            final endIndex = str.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
            temp = str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
            print("ID $temp");
          }
```

**or**

```
          Iterable<Match>? matches = RegExp(r' id\W*([a-z0-9\s]+,)').allMatches(str);
          for (var m in matches) {
            print(m.group(0));
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that string is not changing in any condition other wise logic may fail..

```dart
void main() {
  // actual string
  // String x="RunHyperlink : {classid: 25510, id: 2, mad_key: 32835}";
  String x = snapshot.data[index];
  
  // remove unwanted substring form string
  List keyValues= x.replaceAll('RunHyperlink : {','').replaceAll('}','').replaceAll(', ',',').split(",");
  
  //create map
  Map map = {};

  // run for loop to split key and value
  for (var element in keyValues){
    print(element.split(": ")[0]);
    map.addAll({element.split(": ")[0] : element.split(": ")[1]});
  }
  
  // get the id balue
 
  print(map['id']);
  
}
```